# check if user is visiting pure root url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to run a js script if a user is visiting my site's root url. I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(location.pathname == "/") {
        window.open ('#107','_self',false);
    }
</script>
```

However http://example.com/?foo=bar#hash will also run the script, since the pathname excludes the query string and location hash.

It currently behaves like this:

```
http://example/                  Root
              /?querystring      Root
              /#hash             Root
              /page              Not root
```

I want it to behave like this:

```
http://example/                  Root
              /?querystring      Not root
              /#hash             Not root
              /page              Not root
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I needed your opposite case so Your code as it is without a fix was what I exactly after, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.location.href` instead

Comment: I edited my code to the following and it worked:

`<script type="text/javascript">
 if(window.location.href == "http://example.com/") {
  window.open ('#107','_self',false);
 }
</script>`

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the pathname, location.search and location.hash.

```
var fullPath = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
if(fullPath == "/") { /* whatever */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just test for all three components:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(location.pathname == "/" && 
        location.hash.length <= 1 && 
        location.search.length <= 1) {
        window.open ('#107','_self',false);
    }
</script>
```